# Dynamically change select dropdown value using jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using two dropdowns in a form for searching. The second dropdown value will change based on the selection of the first one. The ajax request goes but somehow not returning any value from the php script. Any suggestions for change in code?

search.php

```
<select name="shop_name" id="shop_name">
                  <option value="blank">Select one</option>
                  <?php
                  $searchItem = new dbhandler();
                  $shopData = $searchItem->all_data('food_shops');
                  $i = 0;
                  foreach($shopData as $sd) {
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $shopData[$i]->r_id; ?>"><?php echo $shopData[$i]->name; ?></option>
                    <?php $i++; } ?>
 </select>
```

script.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#shop_name").change(function()
{
  var id=$(this).val();
  var dataString = 'id=' + id;
$.ajax
({
  type: "GET",
  url: "dynamic_select.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function(data)
  {
    $("#location").html(data);
  }
  });

  });

  });
```

dynamic_select.php

```
<?php

if($_GET['id']) {

  $crs = $_GET['id'];
?>

  <select name="location" id="location">
<?php
  $searchItem = new dbhandler();
  $searchItem->find('food_shops' , 'r_id', $crs);
  $data = $searchItem->data();
  $j = 0;
  foreach($data as $d) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $data[$j]->address; ?>"><?php echo $data[$j]->address; ?></option>
  </select>
<?php $j++; } } ?>
```

The all_data() queries `SELECT * FROM table_name`
and find() queries `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE r_id = $crs`

Comment: You don't have an `url` option for your ajax call.

Comment: In your ajax you need to add url and pass the id parameter for getting related values.

Comment: ^^^^ + `$("#location").replaceWith(data);`

Comment: @A.OzanEkici gave still not working

Comment: So @AbhijitBorkakoty can you update your question with the ajax url option, so we can look at it.

Comment: @A.OzanEkici done...please have a look

Comment: @AbhijitBorkakoty I don't know much about php but in asp I send data in the ajax as an object like; `data: {id: id}`  Maybe this is the solution for you.

Comment: Welcome - please read how to ask - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Proof read before posting. For example your title has dropdown not drpdown!

Answer (score 1):

you can check your response with inspector looks like following.In your page you just check that what you are getting in your response.you just let open the inspector network>xhr and then select value from your first dropdown. on selection of dropdown it will call the dynamic_select.php and show to inspector and just select response you will be able to see the response there.

[image]

Comment: what was the response for dynamic_select.php?id=7811178?

Comment: Thanks @Alfiza for your help...Found the solution. I was not including the autoload file for the classes. Included that and made sure the correct url goes to the php script. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $("#shop_name").change(function()
    {
      var id=$(this).val();
      var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax
    ({
      type: "GET",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      url : "dynamic_select.php",
      success: function(data)
      {
        $("#location").html(data);
      }
      });

      });

      });
  </script>
```

add the url with id in your ajax script ,change the dynamic_select.php path if required.

Comment: @Alfizamalek You are passing data two times. One at `data `option and one at end of the `url `option.